# How do I update the <p> element inside my HTML dialog box on passing of every minute, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

**My HTML :**

```
<dialog id="wait_dialog">
    <p style="font-family: cursive;" id="report_data">Downloading, please wait..</p>
    <button id="close_wait_dialog">Cancel</button>
</dialog>
```

**My JS :**

```
function generate_complete_input(data){
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/backend.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"data": data}   
    })
}

function geninp(response){
    const arr=JSON.parse(response);
    for(var j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
        //populate table here
    }
}
let arr = ["00001","00002","50003"];

(async() => {
    document.getElementById("wait_dialog").showModal();
    var start = new Date().getMinutes();
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        response = await generate_complete_input(arr[i]);
        geninp(response);
    }
    var end = new Date().getMinutes();
    var remaining_time = end - start; //get the time required to run the for loop (in minutes)
    var inst = setInterval(update_dialog(remaining_time),60000); //update dialog with a message
})();

function update_dialog(time){
    time -= 1;
    document.getElementById("report_data").innerText += "(Remaining time: "+time+" minutes)";
    if(time == 0){
        clearInterval(inst);
        document.getElementById("wait_dialog").close();
    }
}
```

I want to update my `dialog` with the time that was required to run the `for(){}` loop. So I call a `setInterval()` method which will keep on editing the text inside the `dialog` box every minute, until the `time` becomes 0. I've checked my console, there are no errors there.

But, upon executing the code, the `dialog` text never gets edited. It just stays as `Downloading, please wait..`. Where am I going wrong?

**OBJECTIVE:** Suppose, the `for` loop takes **5 mins** to execute. My dialog box, in this case, should be:

```
Downloading, please wait..(Remaining time: 5 minutes)
```

then, after a minute, it should be:

```
Downloading, please wait..(Remaining time: 4 minutes)
Downloading, please wait..(Remaining time: 3 minutes)...
```

And so on.

Comment: what does arr includes? and what about geninp function please provide more debugging details

Comment: I have updated my code, please check. Basically inside the `for` loop, two things are happening, first some values are fetched from the server using `AJAX`, second, an `HTML` table is populated with the values fetched.

Answer (score 1):

i will assume that everything works fine on your backend response and your functions works well,

the way you update the text input is wrong,
this is how you solve your problem

```js
let arr = ["00001","00002","50003"];

(async() => {
    document.getElementById("wait_dialog").showModal();
    // var start = new Date().getMinutes();
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        // response = await generate_complete_input(arr[i]);
        // geninp(response);
    }
    // var end = new Date().getMinutes();
    let start = 5, end = 10;
    var remaining_time = end - start; //get the time required to run the for loop (in minutes)
    
    update_dialog(remaining_time); //update dialog with a message
})();


function update_dialog(time){
    let reportText = document.getElementById("report_data").innerText;

    var inst = setInterval(()=> {
        document.getElementById("report_data").innerText = reportText + `(Remaining ${time} minutes)`;
        time -= 1;

        if(time < 0){
            clearInterval(inst);
            document.getElementById("wait_dialog").close();
        }
    }, 1000); // am using 1 second just to demonstrate
}
```

```html
<dialog id="wait_dialog">
  <p style="font-family: cursive;" id="report_data">Downloading, please wait..</p>
  <button id="close_wait_dialog">Cancel</button>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you have errors in your console. Press F12 and look at the console tab. There will be some red lines showing errors.

The most likely cause is that your setInterval call is formatted incorrectly. You need to pass a function to this, not the result of one.

Change to this:

```
(async() => {
    document.getElementById("wait_dialog").showModal();
    var start = new Date().getMinutes();
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        response = await generate_complete_input(arr[i]);
        geninp(response);
    }
    var end = new Date().getMinutes();
    var remaining_time = end - start; //get the time required to run the 
for loop (in minutes)
    var inst = setInterval(() => 
    { 
        remaining_time -= 1; 
        update_dialog(remaining_time); 
    }, 60000); //update dialog with a message
})();

function update_dialog(time){
    document.getElementById("report_data").innerText += "(Remaining time: "+time+" minutes)";
    if(time == 0){
        clearInterval(inst);
        document.getElementById("wait_dialog").close();
    }
}
```

Comment: by using += in the interval this will append "(Remaining time: "+time+" minutes)" every minute so you have something like this (Remaining time: 5 minutes)(Remaining time: 4 minutes)(Remaining time: 3 minutes)